# Determining 3D position after time

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate an object's angle to a fixed point after a certain amount of time, given the following information:

1: The origin 0,0,0 is your stationary point of view (the aforementioned fixed point)
2: The distance and bearings to the object from the origin are known
3: The bearings are given in one horizontal angle and one vertical angle
4: The speed and heading of the object are known and constant

I will use the following values in an example:

1: Object speed: 100 m/s
2: Object starting distance from origin: 2000 m
3: Object bearing from origin: 1°00′00″ horizontal, 2°00′00″ vertical
4: Object heading: 130°00′00″ horizontal, 5°00′00″ vertical
5: Position to calculate after t = 60 s

I'm guessing the solution would involve the following method:

1: Determine the starting coordinates of the object, based on the horizontal and vertical bearings, and the distance.
2: Use the object's starting coordinates, its heading, and its speed multiplied by t = 60 to determine its coordinates after the specified time.
3: Determine the angle from the origin to the coordinates at t = 60.

It looks like there is a lot of trigonometry involved in this. Perhaps this is easier to solve than it looks, but to me, it appears to have a lot of steps involved in it. Or perhaps there is a better method to solving this? Some formula I'm unaware of?

Comment: I'm not sure what any of that means. As for what I tried to do, I thought I could use the distance formula and solve for the variables, as I knew the distance and the origin coordinates, but I quickly realised that I'd be solving for three unknowns (the x, y and z of the starting coordinates).

Comment: The bearing from origin to the start? That's the known information listed in point three of the example. Or did you mean what I did to try and solve for the bearing from origin to the t=60 coordinates? If the latter, I didn't make it that far.

Comment: Ok i see the edit. This is trivial then.. Just apply the line equation and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You list an object bearing from the origin, presumably that is at the start of your time period.  That gives you an $(x,y,z)$ based on the distance which we can call $d$.  Then add the vector that is the object motion in $60$ seconds.  That will give a final location that depends on $d$.  You still don't have any information that allows you to measure $d$.  It started somewhere on a ray from the origin and is now on a different ray, but you can't find the point along the ray.  Once you find another piece of data to determine $d$ you will have a unique solution, which will involve a bunch of trig to change angles into distances.  Why are you opposed to the trig?  That just generates constants to multiply by.

Comment: I thought d would be the speed of the object multiplied by the time you want to solve for. Speed of 100 m/s with t=60 would be 6000. Or did I misunderstand what you meant by missing information?

Comment: That tells us how far it moved, but we don't know where it started.  If it was way far away at the start that much motion won't change the angles we observe it at much.  If it started very near the origin, the angles at the end will be the direction of motion.

Comment: Oh, that would probably be me not clarifying the post correctly. The starting distance was 2000 m. The one I mentioned in the second point in the example section. I'll edit that to be clearer. EDIT: Done. So at t=0, it is 2000 m from the origin. At t=60, it has moved 6000m.

Comment: @Hiigaran:  I missed the $2000$m.  Then your approach is exactly correct.  Yes, it involves some trig functions, but what is the problem with that?  You need five per point, so initial position, motion vector, final look angle are no more than fifteen.

Comment: Okay, I've plugged this all into a spreadhsheet to help see things better, but I feel like something is still wrong. Right now, I'm using trigonometry for the first part with the horizontal angle, then a separate one for the vertical. But that wouldn't work, would it? The distance 2000 would be the hypotenuse of the triangles made when calculating the horizontal and vertical triangles first, no? How do I do that?

Comment: Just do everything in Cartesian coordinates.  Where do you measure the bearings from?  If from the $x$ axis, the starting position is $(2000 \cos 1^\circ \cos 2^\circ, 2000 \sin 1^\circ \cos 2^\circ, 2000 \sin 2^\circ)$  Compute the displacement the same way.  Add that to the starting position.  You will need some $\arccos$ and $\arcsin$ functions to get the angles at the end.

Comment: The confusion continues. Cartesian works perfectly. Using these values gives me X, Y and Z coordinates that when I put back into the 3D distance formula will give me 2000. However, when I tried putting the coordinates into Google's calculator, I got different coordinates than the calculations in a spreadsheet. The former had 1998.47722991, 34.8835498057, 69.798993405. The latter had 112.2462455438, 103.964272821, 1994.1394661202. Oddly enough, both have a distance of 2000 from 0, 0, 0. So which one is right? Or are neither correct?

Comment: You are probably putting degrees into the spreadsheet but it expects radians.  The first set looks right since $1^\circ \approx \frac 1{57} \approx \sin 1^\circ$

Comment: Odd. The formula I used in the spreadsheet for X was =2000*COS(DEGREES(1))*COS(DEGREES(2)) for that exact reason, but if the first set is correct, I guess I'll stick with that. So now I assume I repeat the process with the Cartesian formula for the second step, but since 0, 0, 0 is not the starting point this time, I need to do something else, don't I?

Comment: You compute the $x,y,z$ displacements from the motion.  The total displacement is $60\cdot 100=6000$ and you apply the same trig functions to get the components.  Add that to the starting location and you have the ending location.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured it out. Something seemed to just click with Cartesian and spherical formulas, so after working with those, then doing some translation, I'm hoping I've solved it. I tried with three more examples after fixing the degrees/radians issue on my spreadsheet: https://snag.gy/FSGsAW.jpg See anything that looks wrong? Rows 39, 41 and 42 should have the solutions.